# Autohotkey - How to detect all input areas/checkboxes in an application?

Tags: screen-scraping, autohotkey

Is there a way to detect input areas such as textboxes and checkboxes within an application? I want to label each input area with a number so I can jump between input fields with AHK using my keyboard.

For example: Once the script is activated and active window is Google Chrome, Chrome could have its address bar labeled #1. When I press "1", the cursor will be directed to that area.

I'm basically trying to create a workaround for applications that are not very keyboard friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Windows applications use standard windows elements. 
For these...

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm - with the ControlList parameter, gets a list of all standard controls.
For those:

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm - can get the type of control, and

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetPos.htm - can get position and dimensions of the control.

Some can also be controlled through COM: https://gist.github.com/kheybot/7026077#automation-of-office-applications

---

Commandline and console programs can sometimes be communicated with directly, using the standard streams (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR, LPTn, PRN, NUL), or you can communicate with the terminal that displays the program using COM or WSH:
https://gist.github.com/kheybot/7026077#interact-with-command-line

This is important for a lot of legacy data-entry programs.

---

Browsers (eg Chrome), unfortunately, can't use these heavyweight components, because there may be far too many on a page, but there are other options for communicating with them, such as COM, DDE, etc to communicate with the DOM:
https://gist.github.com/kheybot/7026077#browser-automation

For a web browser, I'd be inclined to go for a hybrid approach, combining AHK-handling of the web browser's input areas (address bar, etc) with a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script to handle input fields within the web page itself - the Javascript will be better able to handle input areas using the DOM than any screen-scraping software could. There's also the possibility of using a functional-testing suite like Selenium for automation, and using the browser's plug-in functionality to write an extension to handle its UI.

This would mean that you now have TWO programming problems, of course...

---

Java applications, Flash applications, HTML5 applications, some graphic design software, and just about all computer games are essentially just graphics, with no way of externally identifying controls.

For these, you have to use basic screen scraping techniques: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm and http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PixelSearch.htm to identify specific areas, which can only really be done by individually programming the specific control.

One option for generic detection, though, is to have something that detects shadows (drop shadows, buttonized components, etc) and allows you to tab between and send a click to the components detected that way. Unfortunately, modern flat design meant this won't always work, so you could also try searching for flat-colored rectangles... except sometimes they have curved corners. Because graphic designers hate people.

---

At this point, you will hopefully see that what you have here is an infinite rabbithole of fractal complexity.

You can make a simple ControlGet solution which doesn't work for a lot of applications you would use regularly... or you can create a hybrid approach that targets many applications individually, while also trying to have a generic solution for unrecognized apps.

If you are creating this for your own use, I'd say aim for making it work with the apps you know and use regularly, and that should be enough.

If you're writing it as accessibility software for others to use, I'd say aim for having it user-configurable for each application: let them control what input element they want to click, and in what order, because auto-detection will never work perfectly, and will only rarely pick the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, if the number of check boxes and their position in the application is fixed and you know on which machine the automation takes place.

Please research ImageSearch on how to locate them from screenshots.

If you know the X/Y position of the checkbox in the window, you can also use PixelGetColor to check if a check is visible or not.

You should also examine your application with the included AutoIt Spy. This program shows you, what it can see in the application window.

To get your labelling, checkout the Gui commands. If you make you gui transparent and don't give focus, you can write labels on top of the application.